# Best Practice: Keeping .Net Console Application Open- Console.ReadKey() or Threading.Thread.Sleep(Threading.Timeout.Infinite)

Tags: vb.net, console-application

I have read that to keep a .Net Console Application Open

you can either use
`Console.ReadKey()` or `Threading.Thread.Sleep(Threading.Timeout.Infinite)`

hence like the

> press any key to continue...

what are their differences and impact on the system

are there other ways we can use

trying to convert a UI interface that runs continuously updating to a console application instead and if possibly minimize cpu usage.

Comment: Both these options will in effect stop program execution indefinitely rather than just keep the console open, is that *really* what you want to happen?  Or is supposed to be preforming some task in a loop?

Comment: I will be integrating different process of updating in this one console app. so the logic will  be to ask the user if he will performing other tasks if yes show menu if not close the system.

Comment: While I would suggest ReadKey() then as that will allow you to take user input